# Populate a value in a column based off value in another column in mysql

Tags: mysql

Attempting to create a "view" in MySQL and want to update a rows value based off the value in another field. An Example would be

```
Order   Value
RT123   $14 
CL123   $14 
RT145   $12 
CL145   $12
```

What I am trying to accomplish is...

```
Order   Value
RT123   $14 
CL123   $0 
RT145   $12 
CL145   $0
```

What I was thinking was some sort of nested select statement... Where Order NOT BEGIN 'RT*' THEN VALUE = 0;
Any help on how to get the desired outcome would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple CASE statement would suffice here:

```
SELECT Order, 
    CASE WHEN Order NOT LIKE 'RT%' THEN '$0' ELSE Value END as Value 
FROM table
```

In the form of an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE table
SET Value = '$0'
WHERE Order NOT LIKE 'RT%';
```